# Find the Borders from a position array Python 3

Tags: image-processing, opencv3.0, python-3.8, edges, neighbours

I'm finding the borders in an image with python, first i create neighborhoods, with a gray scale image, then i have to find the points that connect the neighborhoods i created (edges).

Here is an example of my neighborhoods array. The values [x,y] represent the positions of the pixel that forms part of the neighborhood. [This is the diagram of the neighborhood (vecinos) array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OWJU.png)

```
[ [ [0,0], [0,1],[0,2] ], [ [1,0], [1,1],[1,2] ] ]
```

[A google drive link to the full neighborhood array in a txt form](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11XgiUpfK4thUWpQ-lMqcwhz5BApnCFPy/view?usp=sharing)

And this is the function that i use to detect borders

```
def getPoints(vecinos, img):
    print('puntos')
    length = len(vecinos)
    bol = np.zeros(img.shape,img.dtype)
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(length):
            if not i == j:
                for val2 in vecinos[i]:
                    for val1 in vecinos[j]:
                        res1 = abs(val1[0] -  val2[0])
                        res2 = abs(val1[1] - val2[1])
                        if( (res1 == 0 or res1 == 1) and (res2 == 1 or res2 == 0) ):
                            print('borde')
                            bol[ val1[0],val1[1] ] = 1
                            bol[ val2[0],val2[1] ] = 1
    return bol
```

the result of this function returns an array with the same height and width the 1 are identified as borders the rest is 0. Here is an example of the numpy array that results. [this is a txt of a result i loaded to my google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XFB7IjnDYFPfG2rgogts25_T8iE-VKrf/view?usp=sharing)

this function returns an array with 0 and 1, the 1 are the borders detected.
I want to make this faster, it works fine but it takes long when the image is bigger than 100 px

Comment: Maybe a diagram would help showing what a *"position array"* and a *"neighbourhood"* look like... and another one showing what the expected *"answer"* looks like.

Comment: Hey i added the diagram so you can understand me better as well i added some links to the expected answer array i'm looking for